Reading from "node:fs/promises" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme) in Angular 17
The application works all good when running ng serve and ng build. But when I run ng test, it throws the following errors:
node:fs/promises - Error: Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:fs/promises" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.

node:fs - Error: Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:fs" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.

node:path - Error: Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:path" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.

node:url - Error: Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:url" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.

I have asked GPT and searched around on the internet. Here's what I have checked:
"Remove the 'node:' and just use things like 'fs', 'path', etc."
Those "node:xxx" aren't even existing in my code base. So this won't work. I did find them in several of my dependencies, but I won't be able to modify them.
"Modify your webpack.conf.js"
I am in Angular 17 so I don't even have a webpack.conf.js. When I created one and made some modification there, however, the app itself breaks.
"Check your webpack version, there could be a version inconsistency."
Have checked, there's only one version: 5.9.4.
The majority of the questions raised around this are having issues in their ng serve or ng build, so some of their solutions won't work for me. I am using Karma for auto testing if that matters.

I faced the same issue when I was using next.js, Add this webpack config to your next config file, in my case it worked, If you're using any other webpack related config, try to adopt to:
webpack: (config, { webpack }) => {
      config.experiments = { ...config.experiments, topLevelAwait: true };
      config.externals["node:fs"] = "commonjs node:fs";
      config.resolve.fallback = {
        ...config.resolve.fallback,
        fs: false,
    };
      config.plugins.push(

        new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
          /^node:/,
          (resource) => {
            resource.request = resource.request.replace(/^node:/, '');
          },
        ),
      );
  
      return config;
   }

It enables modern features like top-level await, externalizes Node.js modules like fs, and adjusts module imports by removing the node: prefix for compatibility.
